# summing the sum in mysql

Tags: mysql

Say If I get a resultset in mysql as :

```
ID  count(posts)
101 2344
102 3245
103 232
104 23
```

Is there any way to get the tota count of count(posts) in the query itself,
like this?

```
ID  count(posts)
101 2344
102 3245
103 232
104 23
   ------
    5844
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  id, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        id WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. I never knew something like this existed. Thanks.